# Biztalk remove element if no child

Tags: xslt, biztalk

How do I remove empty elements from the output file ?

I have a input file like this:

```
 <Root>
  ...
   <Header>
    <Rows>
      ...
     </Rows>
     <Rows>
      ...
     </Rows>
   </Header>
   ....
 </Root>
```

That maps to this:

```
<Root>
  ...
  <OutHeader>
    <OutRows>
     ...
     </OutRows>
     <OutRows>
      ...
     </OutRows>
   </OutHeader>
   ...
 </Root>
```

Thats all fine, but when the input file looks like this:

```
<Root>
  ...
   <Header>
   </Header>
   ....
 </Root>
```

It maps to

```
<Root>
  ...
  <OutHeader>
  </OutHeader>
   ...
 </Root>
```

And thats not valid (I can not change the schema)

so if Header element has no child elements the OutHeader element can not be in the outfile

How do I do that using the functoids in Biztalk maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited-

1. Link `<Rows>` to an Index Functoid with the second parameter as 1.
2. Link the Index Functoid to a Logical Existence Functoid.
3. Link the Logical Existence Functoid to `<OutHeader>`.

This means basically create `<OutHeader>` only if the first  element exists.